# WAToolKit iOS Azure Table Storage iPad

Tags: ios, azure, ipad, storage

I'm using Azure table storage to save my data and I'm using the Azure Toolkit for iOS,
I want to add filters, now I'm creating them like this:

> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Status == 'Reservacion'"];
>
>   NSString* filter = [WAAzureFilterBuilderfilterStringWithPredicate:predicate error:nil];
>   NSLog(@"FILTER: %@", filter);

The log prints "Status eq "Reservacion"" but it's not working, I'm getting this message:

> ERROR: One of the request inputs is not valid.

I've tried these ways:

```
"Status == Reservacion"
"Status = Reservacion"
"Status == \"Reservacion\""
"Status eq 'Reservacion'"
```

but none of them is working.

Has anyone done this?
Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I realize this post is almost a year old, but have you looked at the  new toolkit? https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios. I don't see the `WAAzureFilterBuilder` class in the repo, but it seems there is a new way to do this using `+ (WATableFetchRequest *)fetchRequestForTable:(NSString *)tableName predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate error:(NSError **)error`